# how should I call all functions in a variadic parameter pack if the function return type is void?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I have a parameter pack full of default constructable and then callable objects (like the `ExampleFunctor`) and want to call all of them in order (left to right). If the return type is anything besides void I can use an initializer list to do this:

```
struct ExampleFunctor{
    void operator()(){someGlobal = 4;}
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct CallThem {
    void operator()(){
        auto list = {Ts()()...};
    }
}
```

however if the return type is void this trick does not work.

I could wrap all the Ts in a wrapper returning an int but that seems overkill and this code will be ultimately running on a cortex M3 with 32K of flash so the extra function call overhead of the wrapper is a pain if I compile the unit in debug mode (and debugging in release mode makes my brain hurt).

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the comma operator:

```
int someGlobal;

struct ExampleFunctor{
    void operator()(){someGlobal = 4;}
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct CallThem {
    void operator()(){
        int list[] = {(Ts()(),0)...};
        (void)list;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CallThem<ExampleFunctor, ExampleFunctor>{}();
}
```

Btw I'm not using an `initializer_list` here but just an array; try yourself which one / if any of them can be thrown away by the compiler. The `(void)list` is to suppress a warning (unused variable).

Comment: That is, btw, not my invention. I'll try to find out if this is a duplicate.

Comment: wow cool trick! just goes to show one needs to know the whole language!

Comment: couldn't I just write int test = (Ts()()..., 0); and give the compiler much less to clean up?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler should be able to optimize away the function calls here:

```
template <typename H, typename... Tail>
void call(H head, Tail... tail) {
   head();
   call(tail...);
}
template <typename T>
void call(T fn) {
   fn();
}
template <typename... Args>
void callThem() {
   call(Args()...);
}
```

But this is untested. Check the generated assembly for your platform.

Comment: yes is does optimize them away in release mode, I need the debug mode binary to fit in the chip though! I know this is a special case but thats why I stated it as one.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct CallThem;

template<>
struct CallThem<> { void operator()() const {} };

template<typename Tail, typename... Queue>
struct CallThem<Tail, Queue...>
{
    void operator()() const {
        Tail()();
        CallThem<Queue...>()();
    }
};
```

Comment: I know the compiler does optimize the recursive function call away in release mode, I need the debug mode binary to fit in the chip though! I know this is a special case but thats why I stated it as one.