# How would you apply an same operation to a set of independent variables in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, foreach, tuples

**Edit** Totally forgot to mention smth that's obvious to me:

`a_func()` wants to **modify** the `var_xxx`, so the solutions that iterate using a `const` type aren't completely satisfying (although they bring in ideas, for sure).

I feel the answer is simple yet can't find it.

*Given:*

A number (a small number, like 6, 8, 10) of variables of a user class type (precisely, a math vector object), where each variable has to have a unique name, defined by the algorithm (in order to be calculated and then used independently, and to be able to easily consult the paper that the code is based on)

*Do:*

In a piece of code, calculate and initialize those variables, referring to them by name; and then in another piece of code perform an operation on them in a sweep, without having to duplicate the code calling the operation (i.e. a function) for each and every variable.

*Code goes like this:*

```
// in a class declaration
vector_type var_abc, var_efg, var_xyz;

// in a class member function
// "some_math_xxx" pieces are coded inline, not as separate functions
var_abc = /* some_math_abc */;
var_efg = /* some_math_efg */ ;
var_xyz = /* some_math_xyz */ ;
a_func(var_abc); a_func(var_efg); a_func(var_xyz);
```

I mean, I can of course type `a_func(var_xxx)` six or more times. But it, well, feels just wrong to me.

Thought of:

- a hash to store the names of those cars (bad for the math using them later I guess)
- a `std::array<>` of pointers to the vars (bit clumsy but works)
- this code that fails to compile:

  `for (vector_type& vr : { var_abc, var_efg, var_xyz }) { a_func(vr); }`
  (error: `binding const vector_type to reference of type vector_type&`)

How would you solve this? I'd prefer an elegant solution, of course. The standard better be just C++11, though C++14 is ok too if it enables a super cute solution to this problem.

P.S. The question entering form says "the title is subjective and the Q may be closed". I'm sure this is not an opinion-based Q, as I'm not asking to compare the solutions, but to suggest some.

Comment: I rather like the `std::array<>` solution.

Comment: for (const vector_type& vr : ?

Comment: "How would you" sounds opinion based to me, but the question itself doesn't. Have you considered using `std::tie`? I believe this is one of the cases it was made for.

Comment: Your solution would work if you use `std::ref` from `<functional>`, e.g. `for (vector_type& vr : { std::ref(var_abc), std::ref(var_efg), std::ref(var_xyz) }) { a_func(vr); }`

Comment: @thorsan it's a modifying operation, unfortunately

Comment: @nwp could you give an example of how you'd use `std::tie` here? I thought about it but lack the knowledge of this new functionality yet. And , you can't `for_each` over a `std::tuple` easily, can you?

Comment: I'd like a variadic function template, where the first argument is the function and the rest are variable references

Comment: What am I missing? This seems simple: `for ( auto it: std::initializer_list<VecType *>{&vecA, &vecB, &vecC} ) {  doStuff(*it); }` The issue seems to be that you were trying to initialise a reference with a `const` value copied to the implicit `initializer_list`, so just use pointers; they're not to be feared. you probably don't even need to explicitly specify the `initializer_list` type as long as you're not using polymorphic pointers in it. @Hilborn Putting everything through an extra layer of `std::reference_wrapper` seems to be an unnecessary hoop to jump through, just to avoid pointers.

Comment: @Hilborn funny you asked

Comment: @CoffeeandCode `ref` returns a `reference_wrapper`.

Comment: @JonathanMee I neglected his first comment haha

Comment: @Hilborn I believe that I have straight up ganked your answer. I thought I could do this either with `vector`s or `ref` but I cannot solve it with a `vector<vector_type&>`. If you post an answer let me know and I will delete mine.

Comment: Actually `std::tie` doesn't fit here. It is meant to bundle different types and therefore does not support iterating over. Sorry.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode haha :)

Comment: @underscore_d I don't fear pointers, I just wanted to point out that it is possible to iterate over references. It has some syntactic overweight, so I would prefer a variadic template instead. Pointers is a good alternative too

Comment: @JonathanMee no problem. Yes `std::vector` has issues with references, but then again you can use a vector of `std::reference_wrapper` (or pointers) :)

Comment: @underscore_d Yeah, he was just talking about `vector` in response to my faulty solution. An `initializer_list` is the best solution.

Comment: re edit: "the solutions that iterate using a const type aren't completely satisfying" - where are these solutions? I'm struggling to find them. Trick question! All the ones I can see use non-`const` pointers or references (or pointers wrapped to look like references).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you were trying to initialise a reference with a `const` value copied to the implicit `initializer_list`. This container, like all others, cannot contain references. So, instead, you get `const` values, since `initializer_list` (currently? and probably forever) only offers `const` access to its members.

So... just use pointers to the elements. They're not to be feared. This seems simple:

```
for ( auto const it: /* std::initializer_list<VecType *> */ {&vecA, &vecB, &vecC} ) {
    doStuff(*it);
    // N.B. it is a *const, not a const *const!
}
```

You don't need to explicitly specify the `initializer_list` type, as long as you're not using elements of various polymorphic pointer types or that require conversion `operator`s (in which case, you do).

Unless I'm missing something, others' suggestions of putting everything through an extra layer of `std::reference_wrapper` seems to be an unnecessary hoop to jump through, just to avoid pointers for some reason. Other solutions might invoke copies, which could lead to a lot of confusion.

I kinda wish C++ had a range-`for` style 'automatic dereference` for this case, but getting that implemented would probably cause all kinds of syntactic ambiguity, which wouldn't really be worth it when it's simple enough this way.

Comment: I'm sure you're aware that the compiler is going to simplify this code and `reference_wrapper` code to the same assembly, so really it's more about which approach is more readable. Anyway, +1 for a solution that shows an understanding of the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: @JonathanMee Thanks. Yeah, I assume in most cases, `reference_wrapper` is trivial to optimise away. The "unnecessary hoop" was as much about typing as theoretical overhead. :) As a personal convention, since it's most likely optimised to the same thing, I just go directly to pointers, but maybe that's my C past lingering! The clarity of reference semantics could be useful in more complex examples... unless one is willing to use pointers and take a (de)reference at the start of the loop, haha

Comment: @RichardHodges `std::endl`. Sorry, are we just quoting random names? Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: std::addressof(x) is preferable to &x - in case the unary & operator has been overloaded.

Comment: @RichardHodges Sure, of course, but for simple cases where we know that overload is absent, it's just unnecessary typing. I would use it where I couldn't be certain, but in every case so far, I can.

Comment: While I accept your position (and also hate typing), IMHO std::addressof is still preferable since it's explicitly expressive and protects against future interface changes of x; since the standard guarantees that it will always yield the address of x. I find myself using it in place of & in all cases because of this. I liked the simplicity and directness of your answer BTW :)

Comment: @RichardHodges My goodness that's awesome, I didn't even know `addressof` existed. I have learned my new thing for the day!

Comment: @RichardHodges Nope serious, I basically just learn stuff when I see it on http://www.stackoverflow.com and that's the first I've seen of `addressof`. That's pretty much the reason I get on here is to expand my C++ horizons.

Comment: @RichardHodges Thanks! Your points are extremely valid. For now, I'll accept the risk that I add an `operator&` overload later, forget about this, and spend 3 hours baffled by the results. ;-) Thankfully wherever I've needed to use this pattern so far, it's been on classes that would never(?) have any need for an overload, so this saves typing and readability.

Comment: Overloading `operator&` is not something you do lightly. For almost all types, it is simply correct to assume it will never be. `std::addressof` is mostly for generic code or exceptional situations. Using it unnecessarily will cause confusion.

Comment: @filipos Yeah, the only use-case I've seen is a proxy class, to let it return the address of the target, rather than its own. e.g. a packed bitset. This is usually done by `ProxyHost::ProxyReturn &operator[]`, so I needed `ProxyReturn::operator&` to feign the address of the target byte. Even then, I decided I was overcomplicating things and ended up not using the proxy... and _anyway_, if iterating over this, you wouldn't use an `initializer_list{&of, &pointers}` - you would use a `for` loop over `operator[]`, making this all moot. It's hard to imagine a case where one would need both of these

Answer (score 4):

I'd write a recursive function that applies a functor to a set of variables:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename Functor, typename First, typename Second, typename ... Others>
auto apply_over(Functor &&fn, First &&var0, Second &&var1, Others &&... vars){
    fn(std::forward<First>(var0));
    apply_over(std::forward<Second>(var1), std::forward<Others>(vars)...);
}

template<typename Functor, typename Var>
auto apply_over(Functor &&fn, Var &&var){
    fn(std::forward<Var>(var));
}
```

And use it like so:

```
auto main() -> int{
    var_type var0, var1, var2;

    apply_over([](var_type &var){ /* do something with var */ }, var0, var1, var2);
}
```

Or even better (more generic) with C++14:

```
auto main() -> int{
    var_type var0;
    int var1;
    float var2;

    // no need to worry about types!
    apply_over([](auto &var){ var += decltype(var)(1); }, var0, var1, var2);
}
```

Or with your function `a_func`:

```
auto main() -> int{
    var_type var0, var1, var2;

    apply_over(a_func, var0, var1, var2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code: `for (vector_type& vr : { var_abc, var_efg, var_xyz }) { a_func(vr); }` creates an [`initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<T>` is a lightweight proxy object that provides access to an array of objects of type `const T`

So you cannot invoke a modifying function on them.

Instead use [`ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref): `for (auto& vr : { ref(var_abc), ref(var_efg), ref(var_xyz) }) { a_func(vr); }`

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/j0V3GG)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve the effect of *copy pasting the function call without actual copy pasting, then use this **variadic template trick***:

```
template<typename ... Args>
void call_a_func (Args&&... args)
{
  int unused[] = { (a_func(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0) ... }; (void) unused;
}
```

Usage:

```
call_a_func(var_abc, var_efg, var_xyz, var_pqr);
```

I have simplified your problem in this [Demo](http://ideone.com/PZbFG6). You may extend it further. This trick is mentioned at various places in SO, I picked up from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19861008/514235).

Answer (score 1):

If you want an unfolded loop, you might be interested in `for_each_arg`:

```
template<class F, class...Ts>
F for_each_arg(F f, Ts&&...a) {
  return (void)std::initializer_list<int>{(f((Ts&&)a),0)...}, f;
}
```

Usage:

```
for_each_arg(a_func, var_abc, var_efg, var_xyz);
```

Of course, if you have to operate on the same set of variables repeatedly, it might be better to define an array of pointers and use iteration.

References:

https://twitter.com/ericniebler/status/559119062895431680

https://youtu.be/Za92Tz_g0zQ

https://github.com/SuperV1234/cppnow2015

Comment: Although I can't wrap my head around its sheer hackiness, I can tell this looks like a more reusable version of @iammilind's post, as it parameterises the function too. Anyway, to be pedantic, you can't "define an array [or any other container] of references" - at most a container of `reference_wrappers`, i.e. pointers-masquerading-as-references, at which point I'd say it's best just to use pointers directly (though the `ref`-style semantics are probably invaluable in some cases).

Comment: @underscore_d When I wrote about array of references, I was thinking precisely about pointers. I will edit to make that clear.